# How to copy text file in python

Tags: python, file, text, clone

Here's what I want to do:

```
import copy
def printtext(swefile):
    for row in swefile:
        print(row)
text = open("wordsv.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
text2 = copy.copy(text)
printtext(text)
print(text2.readlines())
```

But it is not possible, TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object.
So I wonder if there is a good method for "cloning" the text variable, so that I could print all the lines again. I know that I could just read the file again, but that answer does not solve the bigger problem I have so any suggestion on how to get this done is helpful.

---

Here's the larger context as I haven't been able to solve my problem with your suggestions:

```
with open(textfilename, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as swefile:
    for row in swefile:
        word = row.strip()
        tempfile = copy.copy(swefile)
        l = getFurthest(word,tempfile)
```

The thing that I want to happen here is that i want to send the portion of `swefile` that has not been read yet (i.e. iterated over yet by the for loop) to `getFurthest()`! And I can't send `swefile` because that will make the whole thing read so the iterations in the for loop will stop, right? So how can I send only the portion of the textfile that has been read to `getFurthest()` while still being able to iterate over the rest of it after?

Comment: Erm, if rereading doesn't solve the bigger problem then I'm not sure that I want to know what the bigger problem is...

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make a COPY of the variable 'text'. So I basically want 'text2' to refer to something (is it really called text file?) that is the same as 'text' but I don't want them to be CONNECTED. :)

Comment: Do you want text to be a file object or a list of strings?

Comment: I want it to be the same as what 'text' is, the thing you get when you write {open("textfile.txt","r"]}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid re-opening the file, but want to read it twice, you can use [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek):

```
import copy
def printtext(swefile):
    for row in swefile:
        print(row)
text = open("wordsv.txt","r",encoding='utf-8')
printtext(text)
text.seek(0)
printtext(text)
```

If you just care about the text, you can do this:

```
import copy
def printtext(swefile):
    for row in swefile:
        print(row)
text = open("wordsv.txt","r",encoding='utf-8').readlines()
text2 = copy.copy(text)
printtext(text)
printtext(text2)
```

Here `text` is a list of the lines in `wordsv.txt`, and you then copy the list into text2 (i.e. changing `text` won't change `text2`).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you really do want to wind up with two files for some reason, it's best to use [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to copy it:

```
import shutil

path = "wordsv.txt"
path2= "wordsv2.txt"
shutil.copy(path, path2)
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as text, open(path2, encoding='utf=8') as text2:
    # Do something with text, text2 here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line `text2 = copy.copy(text)` does not work because text is a file object only. To "copy" the text in the file, do as follows:

```
text2 = text.read()
```

Please note that you don't copy the actual text (content), as strings are immutable.

Comment: The problem with that is that I lose `text`, i.e. it becomes "read". I want to keep them both unread.

Comment: @user3128156 than maybe have a look at samGbos answer.